# No puedo acceder a mi server centos desde PhpDesigner, error en hot key verified!! como lo soluciono?

Tags: php, centos, ssh, sftp

Buen dia,

Tengo un problema al quererme conectar a mi servidor centos 6.9, para programar uso phpdesigner, el centos se cambio a otro server y ahora que me quiero volver a conectar no puedo conectarme ya que me sale un error de host key not verified, que debo de hacer para poder trabajar normalmente en phpdesigner.

Por favor necesito ayuda urgente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes que borrar la conexion de tu phpDesigner y volver a conectarte, una vez realizado debera de aceptar la nueva key de conexion, y listo

Answer (score 0):

Busca y borra la carpeta donde se almacenan los Keys,
en mi caso es

```
C:\Users\NAMEUSER\AppData\Roaming\phpDesigner\SFTP\Keys\Server
```

Si la conexión es correcta te pedirá aceptar la nueva key al conectar.